# Realm.IO - Could not map Json

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I have following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "organizationId": {
      "aggregateId": "7cfaf5c0-127a-4cfc-b73b-52a35fd02ffd"
    },
    "organizationName": "OrgName1",
    "address": {
      "city": {
        "cityName": "CItyName1",
        "population": 5
      },
      "region": {
        "regionName": "RegionName1",
        "city": null
      },
      "street": "Street1",
      "houseNumber": "HouseNumber1",
      "zipCode": "1000001"
    },
    "phoneNumber": "123456781",
    "faxNumber": "7894653121"
  }
]
```

Organization model

```
    public class Organization extends RealmObject{

        private OrganizationId organizationId;
        private String organizationName;
        private Address address;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String faxNumber;
...

public class OrganizationId extends RealmObject {

    private String aggregateId;//3a53ac71-e5e0-4b5a-83ae-ff81931d30be
...

public class Address extends RealmObject {

    private City city;
    private Region region;
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zipCode;
...

public class City extends RealmObject
{
    private String cityName;
    private int population;
...

public class Region extends RealmObject {

    private String regionName;
    private City city;
...
```

Got json from HTTP. Converted into String. Then using createAllFromJson method

```
        String json = new String(response, "UTF-8");
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
        realm.createAllFromJson(Organization.class, json);
```

But this is giving following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could
>   not map Json
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onUserException(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:313)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:404)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not map Json
>               at io.realm.Realm.createAllFromJson(Realm.java:680)
>               at io.realm.Realm.createAllFromJson(Realm.java:732)
>               at uz.sunet.wm.data.Api$1.onSuccess(Api.java:61)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:360)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutable method call during read transaction.
>               at io.realm.internal.Table.throwImmutable(Table.java:1639)
>               at io.realm.internal.Table.checkImmutable(Table.java:1245)
>               at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRow(Table.java:368)
>               at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:1037)
>               at io.realm.OrganizationRealmProxy.createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(OrganizationRealmProxy.java:236)
>               at io.realm.RealmJsonImpl.createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(RealmJsonImpl.java:35)
>               at io.realm.Realm.createAllFromJson(Realm.java:678)
>               at io.realm.Realm.createAllFromJson(Realm.java:732)
>               at uz.sunet.wm.data.Api$1.onSuccess(Api.java:61)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:360)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I have check all models inside Organization. Everything seems to be okey. But when I run getting before stated error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Add the @RealmClass annotation to your RealmObject and try again.

Comment: @vzamanillo, but this is giving this error: Cannot resolve symbol 'RealmClass'

Comment: Add this `import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass;` to your import section

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like you're trying to perform a write operation without being on a transaction.

Comment: @Emanuelez, yes, I forgot to open transaction

Comment: `"city": null` null may not accept by Realm, I think.